# Is it possible to assign IRQs in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, irq

For some PCI devices, I use specific IRQs to call interrupt service routines.  If our video card is using the standard "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" driver, our interrupt service routines run great.  However, if I install the NVidia drivers, the video card takes IRQ 16 (which is in use).

I'd like to use the NVidia drivers, but I need it to move to another IRQ.  I've found some instructions for WinXP, but nothing that works in Windows 10.

Comment: UEFI or legacy BIOS?

Comment: BIOS Mode: Legacy

Comment: Wowza, IRQ? Have you checked into disabling IRQ Steering? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/182628/how-to-disable-pci-bus-irq-steering-in-windows Not complete sure if that's applicable, but it may be worth checking out. If you can change where the IRQ assignments come from, you may be able to get around the driver specifying the wrong IRQ.

Comment: music2myear, I've tried going down that path, but I don't see a "PCI Bus" device, and nothing shows an IRQ Steering tab.